# Why are these queries slow in some environments and not others? Can we fix their performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, information-schema

The following stored procedures in a MySQL 5.x environment:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_belongs_to (IN schemaName VARCHAR(100), IN tableName VARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN
        SELECT TABLE_NAME as keyTable, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS keyColumns, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS refTable, GROUP_CONCAT(REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) AS refColumns, CONSTRAINT_NAME AS constraintName
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = schemaName  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
        AND TABLE_NAME = tableName  COLLATE utf8_general_ci
        AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY constraintName;
    END //

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_has_many (IN schemaName VARCHAR(100), IN tableName VARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN
      SELECT REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME AS keyTable, GROUP_CONCAT(REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME) AS keyColumns, TABLE_NAME AS refTable, GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS refColumns, CONSTRAINT_NAME AS constraintName
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = schemaName COLLATE utf8_general_ci
      AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = tableName COLLATE utf8_general_ci
      GROUP BY constraintName;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

In one environment they run in a .03 seconds and in another closer to 1 or even 2 seconds.

Our current best guess is that it is primarily a problem with the number of tables and amount of data in one environment versus another.

Can anyone provide additional insights? And is there a way to accomplish the same thing as these procedures while getting more consistent performance?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to disable the variable [innodb_stats_on_metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata).

According to the MySQL Documentation on `innodb_stats_on_metadata`

> When this variable is enabled (which is the default, as before the
>   variable was created), InnoDB updates statistics during metadata
>   statements such as SHOW TABLE STATUS or SHOW INDEX, or when accessing
>   the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables TABLES or STATISTICS. (These updates are
>   similar to what happens for ANALYZE TABLE.) When disabled, InnoDB does
>   not update statistics during these operations. Disabling this variable
>   can improve access speed for schemas that have a large number of
>   tables or indexes. It can also improve the stability of execution
>   plans for queries that involve InnoDB tables.